# HTML Gap between DIV section when text is placed within it

Tags: html, css

I have a gap between two of my div sections whenever I insert text or a heading. There is no padding between these two sections (The two sections are `.navtop` and `.welcome`) and for some reason there is always a gap between them when I want them to be touching each other if that makes sense. I have tried everything that I know of at the moment to fix them but nothing seems to work. I was doing this earlier and it was all working but I added something and have forgotten what it was that has broken it. Could anyone try to help me please?

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(function() {
  //$("#para").hide();
});

$(".close").click(function() {
  $(".notice").slideUp(500);
});
```

```css
/* Sass Document */

html {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  color: #34495e;
}

.navigation {
  position: sticky;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
}

a:link {
  color: hotpink;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 44px;
}

li {
  float: left;
  color: hotpink;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: hotpink;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Notice Box */

.notice {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: hotpink;
  line-height: normal;
  padding-top: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
}

.subtitle {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.news {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  color: aliceblue;
}

.close {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 250px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.close:hover {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: grey;
}


/* Welcome Box */

.welcome {
  background-color: #333;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: hotpink;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.welcome-title {
  font-size: 36px;
}

.welcome-text {
  font-size: 24px;
}


/* Footer */

.navbot {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>Home Page</title>
</head>

<div class="navtop">
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Level Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Trade</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="notice">
  <div class="button">
    <button type="button" class="close">×</button>
  </div>
  <h3 class="subtitle">Important</h3>
  <p class="news">test</p>
</div>

<div class="welcome">
  <dive class="welcome-message">
    text goes here
  </dive>
</div>

<footer>
  <div class="navbot">
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Terms of Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    Copyright 2017
    <p><a class="ToS" href="">Terms of service</a></p>
  </div>

</footer>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: try adding a div tag under the head, then under the closing div with class welcome.

Comment: I have just tried that and it did not work. I didn't have this problem earlier so what could be causing it now?

Comment: browsers treat HTML differently, try adding a margin-top: 0px; In class welcome

Comment: Still doesnt work. I think it has something to do with the button in the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed answer and new snippet:

1.) Still the same as before: Your `.navbot` rule has `padding-top: 10px;` Set that to zero.

2.) Add `margin: 0` to `.news`: It has a relative position, and although you moved it up with the `bottom` setting, relative means that its original space is reserved for it as it would be if that `bottom` setting wouldn't exist. And that includes a default `margin-bottom` (added by the browser), which extends the parent element - aphenomenon which is also know as "collapsing margins"  (you'll find a lot if you search for that on SO or elsewhere)

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(function() {
  //$("#para").hide();
});

$(".close").click(function() {
  $(".notice").slideUp(500);
});
```

```css
/* Sass Document */

html {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  color: #34495e;
}

.navigation {
  position: sticky;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
}

a:link {
  color: hotpink;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 44px;
}

li {
  float: left;
  color: hotpink;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: hotpink;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Notice Box */

.notice {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: hotpink;
  line-height: normal;
  padding-top: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
}

.subtitle {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.news {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  color: aliceblue;
  margin: 0;
}

.close {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 250px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.close:hover {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: grey;
}


/* Welcome Box */

.welcome {
  background-color: #333;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: hotpink;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.welcome-title {
  font-size: 36px;
}

.welcome-text {
  font-size: 24px;
}


/* Footer */

.navbot {
  padding-top: 0px;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>Home Page</title>
</head>

<div class="navtop">
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Level Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Trade</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="notice">
  <div class="button">
    <button type="button" class="close">×</button>
  </div>
  <h3 class="subtitle">Important</h3>
  <p class="news">test</p>
</div>

<div class="welcome">
  <dive class="welcome-message">
    text goes here
  </dive>
</div>

<footer>
  <div class="navbot">
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Terms of Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    Copyright 2017
    <p><a class="ToS" href="">Terms of service</a></p>
  </div>

</footer>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: I missed a line of code. Sorry that was my fault. The line is:
    <button type="button" class="close">X</button>
It goes right under <div class="welcome-message"> . Sometimes it causes the gap and sometimes it doesn't. im am lost with why this happens.

Comment: Edit your question accordingly. BTW, I think you also missed other lines of code - you have no `body` tag, you have no CSS for `.navtop`...

Comment: The button doesn't make a difference - I added it to the code in my snippet. It's still that 10px padding-top on `.navbot`  which you have to erase

Comment: I haven't actually made the .navtop yet that is on my todo list but as for the body tag, Thank for reminding me.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Earlier I was having this problem and I was just so lost but now that you have cleared it up thanks so much!

Comment: Just wanted to bump this as my code was wrong at the time. Sorry. But now I have it updated and you can see the problem. If you run my snippet you will see that there is a gap between the "Important" box and the "Text goes here" box. I have tried everything suggested above to fix it but none of that has worked for me. Any other soloutions.

Comment: please note my changed answer